# the latest spring-rabbit don't support encoder tag?

Tags: java, spring, logback, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a question about this, i am going send the logback logs to rabbit, and i use spring-rabbit, as i need to send the data with json format, so i used LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder, here are my configuration

```
<appender name="AMQP" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.logback.AmqpAppender">
    <!--<layout>-->
    <!--<pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>-->
    <!--</layout>-->
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <pattern>
            <pattern>
                { "level": "%level" }
            </pattern>
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
    <host>127.0.0.1</host>
    <port>5672</port>
    <username>guest</username>
    <password>guest</password>
    <routingKeyPattern>testroute</routingKeyPattern>
    <exchangeName>logs</exchangeName>

    <declareExchange>true</declareExchange>
    <generateId>true</generateId>
    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
    <durable>true</durable>
    <deliveryMode>PERSISTENT</deliveryMode>

</appender>
```

but when i start the application, i got the error as below :

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@16:88 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@18:22 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][pattern]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@19:26 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][pattern][pattern]]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:276)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
```

Comment: You need to show your configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell i have updated the configuration file, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct the `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.logback.AmqpAppender` is a `AppenderBase` extension, not an `OutputStreamAppender` which supports that `encoder` option.

However I'm pretty sure we can add support for it and instead of raw `msgBody.getBytes()` call already `this.encoder.encode(event)`.

The JIRA on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-760.